# Popup Button not working inside Ajax success via JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a button that is passed through JSON into a div on my home.php page.
The button is passed perfectly and shows inside its designated div. But when I click the button my popup that's within the comments.php page that is included in the home.php page doesn't popup.

Insert.php (Json is passed back to home.php)

```
$posts['shared_button']="<a style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$row['streamitem_id']."'onclick='document.getElementById('lights".$row['streamitem_id']."').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'' class='pop' title='Share this' href='#'>Share</a>";
```

home.php (Success function)

```
success: function(data){ 
    $.each(data.userpost, function(i, response) {
    $("#newmsg").html(""); 
    if (response.streamitem_type_id == 1 && response.stopcomments == 1) { 
    $("#homestatusid").prepend("<div id='streamshare'>"+response['shared_button']+"</div>");
    }
```

comments.php (Popup div)

```
<div id="lights<? echo $streamitem_data['streamitem_id']; ?>"></div>
```

The popup works just how it should on the client side using the standard html and php, it's only when I try to use an ajax-ed version of the same button.

UPDATE - The original button is actually inside the comments.php along with the div it calls as where the ajax calling json is in home.php. Could this be a reason as I didn't think it would matter if php pages are included as all the html is in available!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have unbalanced quotes. You use single quotes for the attribute values of your button as well as in the attribute content:

```
onclick='document.getElementById('...')'
```

You can do that but then you have to escape the inner single quotes (`\'`).

Check your browser console for errors when you click the button.

Comment: I updated to this 

`<a  style="cursor:pointer;"  id="'.$row['streamitem_id'].'" onclick="document.getElementById(\'lights'.$row['streamitem_id'].'\').style.display="block";document.getElementById(\'fade\').style.display="block"" class="pop" title="Share this" href="#">Share</a>`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: (function(event){document.getElementById('lights1299').style.display=
})

Comment: You missed the `display="block"` part. You have to use single quotes there too: `<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="'.$row['streamitem_id'].'" onclick="document.getElementById(\'lights'.$row['streamitem_‌​id'].'\').style.disp‌​lay=\'block\';document‌​.getElementById(\'fa‌​de\').style.display=‌​\'block\'" class="pop" title="Share this" href="#">Share</a>`